# Google storage : rename object using patch does not work

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to rename object using patch and i am getting this error: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/patch

```
"errors": [{
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidParameter",
    "message": "Value 'test rename.qgm' in content does not agree with value 'arson accelerant headspace lab.qgm'. This can happen when a value set through a parameter is inconsistent with a value set in the request."
}]
```

Otherwise, to rename using gstuil it performs a copy from source to destination followed by removing the source for each object.

Can we rename object in single operation through the Google API instead two operations?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, there is no rename operation. The closest thing is copying the object to its new name, and then deleting the original.